# Why will to_datetime handle positive timezones (UTC+) fine, but not negative timezones (UTC-)?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone

I've been using Pandas to convert a .CSV file into a format that's readable on another system and I'm close to finishing it, but I just can't get it to work with timezones that are negative (UTC-1, -2 etc)

Here is the code I'm using, it's not the tidiest, but it gets the job done for UTC+ timezones, can you see why it might not be handling UTC- timezones correctly?

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

import sys
import io
sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.detach(), encoding = 'utf-8')
sys.stderr = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stderr.detach(), encoding = 'utf-8')

df = pd.read_csv('CONCACAF_First_Round.csv', index_col=False)
df['starttime'] = df['starttime'].str.replace('\s+', '')
df.insert(loc=2, column='season', value='2020')
df.insert(loc=6, column='awayscore', value='')
df.insert(loc=8, column='round_a', value='1')
df['venue'] = df['venue'].str.split(',').str[0]
df[['homescore', 'awayscore']] = df['homescore'].str.split('–',expand=True)
df['awayscore'] = df['awayscore'].str.split(' ').str[0]
df['starttime'] = df['starttime'].str.replace('UTC', ' UTC')
df['datepicker'] = df['datepicker'] + (' ') + df['starttime']
del df['starttime']
df[['datepicker', 'time', 'UTC']] = df.datepicker.str.split(" ", expand=True)
df['datepicker'] = df['datepicker'] + ' ' + df['time']
del df['time']
df['datepicker'] = df['datepicker'] + ' ' + df['UTC']
df['datepicker'] = df['datepicker'].str.replace('±', '+')
df['datepicker'] = df['datepicker'].str.replace('UTC', '')
del df['UTC']
df['datepicker'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datepicker'], utc=True)
df.insert(loc=1, column='starttime', value='')
df['starttime'] = df['datepicker'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
df['datepicker'] = df['datepicker'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(df.head(10))
```

This is what it returns with negative timezones

```
dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: 2015-03-25 19:30 −4
```

This is what it returns when it works correctly with UTC+ timezones

```
datepicker starttime season  hometeam awayteam homescore awayscore              venue round_a
0  2019-09-04  13:00:00   2020  Ethiopia  Lesotho         0         0  Bahir Dar Stadium       1
```

### Data: [`CONCACAF_First_Round.csv`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OZ9qrRkTDYizBeNdRGB7tiYyGKBRphRw/view)

```py
# copy the data to the clipboard and read with
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')

datepicker,starttime,hometeam,awayteam,homescore,venue
2015-03-25,19:30 UTC−4,Bahamas,Bermuda,0–5,"Thomas Robinson Stadium, Nassau"
2015-03-29,15:00 UTC−3,Bermuda,Bahamas,3–0,"Bermuda National Stadium, Devonshire"
2015-03-26,19:00 UTC−4,British Virgin Islands,Dominica,2–3,"Windsor Park, Roseau (Dominica)[note 2]"
2015-03-29,17:00 UTC−4,Dominica,British Virgin Islands,0–0,"Windsor Park, Roseau"
2015-03-22,19:00 UTC−4,Barbados,U.S. Virgin Islands,0–1,"Barbados National Stadium, Bridgetown"
2015-03-26,15:30 UTC−4,U.S. Virgin Islands,Barbados,0–4,"Addelita Cancryn Junior High School Ground, Charlotte Amalie"
2015-03-23,20:00 UTC−4,Saint Kitts and Nevis,Turks and Caicos Islands,6–2,"Warner Park, Basseterre"
2015-03-26,19:00 UTC−4,Turks and Caicos Islands,Saint Kitts and Nevis,2–6,"TCIFA National Academy, Providenciales"
2015-03-23,18:00 UTC−6,Nicaragua,Anguilla,5–0,"Nicaragua National Football Stadium, Managua"
2015-03-29,17:00 UTC−4,Anguilla,Nicaragua,0–3,"Ronald Webster Park, The Valley"
2015-03-25,20:00 UTC−6,Belize,Cayman Islands,0–0,"FFB Stadium, Belmopan"
2015-03-29,19:00 UTC−5,Cayman Islands,Belize,1–1,"Truman Bodden Sports Complex, George Town"
2015-03-27,20:00 UTC−4,Curaçao,Montserrat,2–1,"Ergilio Hato Stadium, Willemstad"
2015-03-31,19:00 UTC−4,Montserrat,Curaçao,2–2,"Blakes Estate Stadium, St. John's"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `fix_starttime` breakdown

- The main issue with the data is `−` is not the correct symbol, `-`. Note that it's slightly longer.

  - Replace `'−'` with `'-'`
  - Replace `' UTC'` with `':00 '`
  - Converts `'19:30 UTC−4'` to `'19:30:00 -4'`
- The `fix_date` function, does the following, with `'19:30:00 -4'`

  - `y = v.split(' ')` → `y = ['19:30:00', '-4']`
  - `z= y[1][0] + y[1][1:].zfill(2) + '00'` → `z = '-' + '0400'` → `z = '-0400'`

    - [`str.zfill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) fills the `str` with zeros to fit the length `width`, 2 in this case. So `'4'` becomes `'04'` and `'10'` stays `'10'`.
  - `t = y[0]` → `t = '19:30:00'`
  - `return 19:30:00-0400`
- Combine `datepicker` and a properly formatted `starttime`, and convert it to a `datetime64[ns, UTC]` formatted column.

```py
import pandas as pd

# read the file
df = pd.read_csv('CONCACAF_First_Round.csv')

# function
def fix_starttime(v: str) -> str:
    y = v.split(' ')
    z = y[1][0] + y[1][1:].zfill(2) + '00'
    t = y[0]
    return t + z


# fix starttime
df['starttime'] = df.starttime.str.replace('−', '-').str.replace(' UTC', ':00 ').apply(fix_starttime)

# create datetime column in datetime64[ns, UTC] format
df['utc_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.datepicker + 'T' + df.starttime, utc=True)
```

### Consolidated

```py
# read the file
df = pd.read_csv('CONCACAF_First_Round.csv')

# fix starttime
df['starttime'] = df.starttime.str.replace('−', '-').str.replace(' UTC', ':00 ').str.split(' ').apply(lambda y: y[0] + y[1][0] + y[1][1:].zfill(2) + '00')

# create datetime column in datetime64[ns, UTC] format
df['utc_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.datepicker + 'T' + df.starttime, utc=True)
```

### Extras

- Once there is a column with a datetime format, use the pandas [`.dt` accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#dt-accessor) to extract datetime components.

```py
# extract time from utc_datetime
df.utc_datetime.dt.time

# extract date from utc_datetime
df.utc_datetime.dt.date
```

### Result

```py
 datepicker      starttime                  hometeam                  awayteam homescore                                                         venue              utc_datetime
 2015-03-25  19:30:00-0400                   Bahamas                   Bermuda       0–5                               Thomas Robinson Stadium, Nassau 2015-03-25 23:30:00+00:00
 2015-03-29  15:00:00-0300                   Bermuda                   Bahamas       3–0                          Bermuda National Stadium, Devonshire 2015-03-29 18:00:00+00:00
 2015-03-26  19:00:00-0400    British Virgin Islands                  Dominica       2–3                       Windsor Park, Roseau (Dominica)[note 2] 2015-03-26 23:00:00+00:00
 2015-03-29  17:00:00-0400                  Dominica    British Virgin Islands       0–0                                          Windsor Park, Roseau 2015-03-29 21:00:00+00:00
 2015-03-22  19:00:00-0400                  Barbados       U.S. Virgin Islands       0–1                         Barbados National Stadium, Bridgetown 2015-03-22 23:00:00+00:00
 2015-03-26  15:30:00-0400       U.S. Virgin Islands                  Barbados       0–4  Addelita Cancryn Junior High School Ground, Charlotte Amalie 2015-03-26 19:30:00+00:00
 2015-03-23  20:00:00-0400     Saint Kitts and Nevis  Turks and Caicos Islands       6–2                                       Warner Park, Basseterre 2015-03-24 00:00:00+00:00
 2015-03-26  19:00:00-0400  Turks and Caicos Islands     Saint Kitts and Nevis       2–6                        TCIFA National Academy, Providenciales 2015-03-26 23:00:00+00:00
 2015-03-23  18:00:00-0600                 Nicaragua                  Anguilla       5–0                  Nicaragua National Football Stadium, Managua 2015-03-24 00:00:00+00:00
 2015-03-29  17:00:00-0400                  Anguilla                 Nicaragua       0–3                               Ronald Webster Park, The Valley 2015-03-29 21:00:00+00:00
 2015-03-25  20:00:00-0600                    Belize            Cayman Islands       0–0                                         FFB Stadium, Belmopan 2015-03-26 02:00:00+00:00
 2015-03-29  19:00:00-0500            Cayman Islands                    Belize       1–1                     Truman Bodden Sports Complex, George Town 2015-03-30 00:00:00+00:00
 2015-03-27  20:00:00-0400                   Curaçao                Montserrat       2–1                              Ergilio Hato Stadium, Willemstad 2015-03-28 00:00:00+00:00
 2015-03-31  19:00:00-0400                Montserrat                   Curaçao       2–2                             Blakes Estate Stadium, St. John's 2015-03-31 23:00:00+00:00
```

Comment: It's not the first time I've been caught out by a symbol being slightly different than the one that is needed, I'll pay special attention to that in the future.

Comment: I'm not sure what the second bullet-pointed section is used for as I have managed to solve my problem with the first bullet-point section. Thank you for lending me your help.

Comment: @SpingoTakagi I wasn't certain of the full scope of the question, so I also did a breakdown of the conversion if needed. `Consolidated` just turns the function into a 1-liner for fixing the `starttime` column.

Comment: thanks for going the extra mile, I wasn't even aware that was possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your "minus" signs are not all minus signs.  For example in your error message:

```
Unknown string format: 2015-03-25 19:30 −4
```

If you copy the second-to-last character that looks like a minus sign into Python as a string you will see:

```
>>> '−'
'\xe2\x88\x92'
```

And that is U+2212, a special [Unicode "minus sign"](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2212) which is different to the '-' on your keyboard.

You'll need to replace those Unicode "minus signs" with plain ASCII minus signs, then it should work.

There was a [Python-ideas discussion about this in 2013](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2013-June/021216.html), "Unicode minus sign in numeric conversions", where [one person said](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2013-June/021236.html):

> As far as supporting non-ASCII plus and minus signs, I'm keen in principle but luke-warm in practice. I think it would be a Nice To Have, and if somebody did the work to identify which characters should be accepted, I'd support adding it as a new feature. But I don't think that the lack of support for non-ASCII numeric signs is a bug.

That thread was ultimately fruitless as everyone beat their hobby horses to death multiple times with side topics like whether Thai numerals should work in `float()`.  A more focused effort to just support U+2212 and a few Unicode "plus" signs might fare better, if someone takes up the task.

Comment: That solved my problem, I'll be much more weary of special symbols when scraping internet data in the future. Thank you for the history lesson too, quite interesting.